# Use character from vector to name object in list

Tags: r, list, vector, character

I have a vector of characters.

```
char_vec = c("hello","world","foo","bar")
```

How can I assign a character (or index) from that vector to name an object in a list?

So instead of doing
`list("hello"=1,"world"=2)`

```
$hello  1
$world  2
```

I want to do:

```
list(as.character(char_vec[1])=1,as.character(char_vec[2])=2)
```

For this I get an error

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:31: unexpected '='
1: list(as.character(char_vec[1])=
                                  ^
Traceback:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
char_vec = c("hello","world","foo","bar")
setNames(list(1,2), char_vec[1:2])
#> $hello
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $world
#> [1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `setNames`

```
setNames(as.list(seq_along(char_vec)), char_vec)
```

-output

```
$hello
[1] 1

$world
[1] 2

$foo
[1] 3

$bar
[1] 4
```